# Error while building flutter app in IOS simulator using android studio

Tags: ios, flutter

I have built a flutter app in IOS simulator using android studio.Here it throws bunch of errors which is related to my app's plugins.I have also installed cocoa pods and installed it. This is the error I'm getting. Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

```
        Error output from Xcode build:
        ↳
            ** BUILD FAILED **


        Xcode's output:
        ↳
            === BUILD TARGET FirebaseStorage OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
            In file included from /Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/FirebaseMessaging/Firebase/Messaging/FIRMessagingConnection.m:19:
            In file included from /Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/FirebaseMessaging/Firebase/Messaging/Protos/GtalkCore.pbobjc.h:27:
            In file included from /Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Protobuf/GPBProtocolBuffers.h:44:
            /Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Protobuf/GPBWellKnownTypes.h:40:10: warning: non-portable path to file '<protobuf/Any.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
             #impo

    rt <Protobuf/Any.pbobjc.h>
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                 <protobuf/Any.pbobjc.h>
        /Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Protobuf/GPBWellKnownTypes.h:41:10: warning: non-portable path to file '<protobuf/Duration.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
         #import <Protobuf/Duration.pbobjc.h>
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                 <protobuf/Duration.pbobjc.h>
        /Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Protobuf/GPBWellKnownTypes.h:42:10: warning: non-portable path to file '<protobuf/Timestamp.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
         #import <Protobuf/Timestamp.pbobjc.h>
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                 <protobuf/Timestamp.pbobjc.h>
        In file included from /Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/FirebaseMessaging/Firebase/Messaging/FIRMessagingConnection.m:19:
        In file included from /Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/FirebaseMessaging/Firebase/Messaging/Protos/GtalkCore.pbobjc.h:27:
        /Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Protobuf/GPBProtocolBuffers.h:55:10: warning: non-portable path to file '<protobuf/Any.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
         #import <Protobuf/Any.pbobjc.h>
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                 <protobuf/Any.pbobjc.h>
        /Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Protobuf/GPBProtocolBuffers.h:56:10: warning: non-portable path to file '<protobuf/Api.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
         #import <Protobuf/Api.pbobjc.h>
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                 <protobuf/Api.pbobjc.h>
        /Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Protobuf/GPBProtocolBuffers.h:57:10: warning: non-portable path to file '<protobuf/Duration.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
         #import <Protobuf/Duration.pbobjc.h>
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                 <protobuf/Duration.pbobjc.h>
        /Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Protobuf/GPBProtocolBuffers.h:58:10: warning: non-portable path to file '<protobuf/Empty.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
         #import <Protobuf/Empty.pbobjc.h>
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                 <protobuf/Empty.pbobjc.h>
        /Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Protobuf/GPBProtocolBuffers.h:59:10: warning: non-portable path to file '<protobuf/FieldMask.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on d

isk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
     #import <Protobuf/FieldMask.pbobjc.h>
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
             <protobuf/FieldMask.pbobjc.h>
    /Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Protobuf/GPBProtocolBuffers.h:60:10: warning: non-portable path to file '<protobuf/SourceContext.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
     #import <Protobuf/SourceContext.pbobjc.h>
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
             <protobuf/SourceContext.pbobjc.h>
    /Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Protobuf/GPBProtocolBuffers.h:61:10: warning: non-portable path to file '<protobuf/Struct.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
     #import <Protobuf/Struct.pbobjc.h>
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
             <protobuf/Struct.pbobjc.h>
    /Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Protobuf/GPBProtocolBuffers.h:62:10: warning: non-portable path to file '<protobuf/Timestamp.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
     #import <Protobuf/Timestamp.pbobjc.h>
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
             <protobuf/Timestamp.pbobjc.h>
    /Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Protobuf/GPBProtocolBuffers.h:63:10: warning: non-portable path to file '<protobuf/Type.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
     #import <Protobuf/Type.pbobjc.h>
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
             <protobuf/Type.pbobjc.h>
    /Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Protobuf/GPBProtocolBuffers.h:64:10: warning: non-portable path to file '<protobuf/Wrappers.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
     #import <Protobuf/Wrappers.pbobjc.h>
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
             <protobuf/Wrappers.pbobjc.h>
    13 warnings generated.
    === BUILD TARGET FirebaseStorage OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
    In file included from /Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/FirebaseMessaging/Firebase/Messaging/FIRMessagingDataMessageManager.m:19:
```

In file included from /Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/FirebaseMessaging/Firebase/Messaging/Protos/GtalkCore.pbobjc.h:27:
In file included from /Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Protobuf/GPBProtocolBuffers.h:44:
/Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Protobuf/GPBWellKnownTypes.h:40:10: warning: non-portable path to file ''; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
 #import 
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         
/Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Protobuf/GPBWellKnownTypes.h:41:10: warning: non-portable path to file ''; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
 #import 
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         
/Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Protobuf/GPBWellKnownTypes.h:42:10: warning: non-portable path to file ''; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
 #import 
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         
In file included from /Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/FirebaseMessaging/Firebase/Messaging/FIRMessagingDataMessageManager.m:19:
In file included from /Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/FirebaseMessaging/Firebase/Messaging/Protos/GtalkCore.pbobjc.h:27:
/Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Protobuf/GPBProtocolBuffers.h:55:10: warning: non-portable path to file ''; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
 #import 
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         
/Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Protobuf/GPBProtocolBuffers.h:56:10: warning: non-portable path to file ''; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
 #import 
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         
/Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Protobuf/GPBProtocolBuffers.h:57:10: warning: non-portable path to file ''; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
 #import 
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         
/Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Protobuf/GPBProtocolBuffers.h:58:10: warning: non-portable path to file ''; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
 #import 
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         
/Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Protobuf/GPBProtocolBuffers.h:59:10: warning: non-portable path to file ''; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
 #import 
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         
/Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Protobuf/GPBProtocolBuffers.h:60:10: warning: non-portable path to file ''; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
 #import 
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         
/Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Protobuf/GPBProtocolBuffers.h:61:10: warning: non-portable path to file ''; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
 #import 
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         
/Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Protobuf/GPBProtocolBuffers.h:62:10: warning: non-portable path to file ''; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
 #import 
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         
/Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Protobuf/GPBProtocolBuffers.h:63:10: warning: non-portable path to file ''; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]

```
 #import <Protobuf/Type.pbobjc.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         <protobuf/Type.pbobjc.h>



 #import <Protobuf/Any.pbobjc.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         <protobuf/Any.pbobjc.h>
/Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Protobuf/GPBProtocolBuffers.h:56:10: warning: non-portable path to file '<protobuf/Api.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
 #import <Protobuf/Api.pbobjc.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         <protobuf/Api.pbobjc.h>
/Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Protobuf/GPBProtocolBuffers.h:57:10: warning: non-portable path to file '<protobuf/Duration.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
 #import <Protobuf/Duration.pbobjc.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         <protobuf/Duration.pbobjc.h>
/Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Protobuf/GPBProtocolBuffers.h:58:10: warning: non-portable path to file '<protobuf/Empty.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
 #import <Protobuf/Empty.pbobjc.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         <protobuf/Empty.pbobjc.h>
/Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Protobuf/GPBProtocolBuffers.h:59:10: warning: non-portable path to file '<protobuf/FieldMask.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
 #import <Protobuf/FieldMask.pbobjc.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         <protobuf/FieldMask.pbobjc.h>
/Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Protobuf/GPBProtocolBuffers.h:60:10: warning: non-portable path to file '<protobuf/SourceContext.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
 #import <Protobuf/SourceContext.pbobjc.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         <protobuf/SourceContext.pbobjc.h>
/Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Protobuf/GPBProtocolBuffers.h:61:10: warning: non-portable path to file '<protobuf/Struct.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
 #import <Protobuf/Struct.pbobjc.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         <protobuf/Struct.pbobjc.h>
/Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Protobuf/GPBProtocolBuffers.h:62:10: warning: non-portable path to file '<protobuf/Timestamp.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
 #import <Protobuf/Timestamp.pbobjc.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         <protobuf/Timestamp.pbobjc.h>
/Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Protobuf/GPBProtocolBuffers.h:63:10: warning: non-portable path to file '<protobuf/Type.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
 #import <Protobuf/Type.pbobjc.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         <protobuf/Type.pbobjc.h>
/Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Protobuf/GPBProtocolBuffers.h:64:10: warning: non-portable path to file '<protobuf/Wrappers.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
 #import <Protobuf/Wrappers.pbobjc.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         <protobuf/Wrappers.pbobjc.h>
13 warnings generated.
=== BUILD TARGET FirebaseStorage OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
In file included from /Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/FirebaseMessaging/Firebase/Messaging/FIRMessagingRmq2PersistentStore.m:27:
In file included from /Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/FirebaseMessaging/Firebase/Messaging/Protos/GtalkCore.pbobjc.h:27:
In file included from /Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Protobuf/GPBProtocolBuffers.h:44:
/Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Protobuf/GPBWellKnownTypes.h:40:10: warning: non-portable path to file '<protobuf/Any.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
 #import <Protobuf/Any.pbobjc.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         <protobuf/Any.pbobjc.h>
/Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Protobuf/GPBWellKnownTypes.h:41:10: warning: non-portable path to file '<protobuf/Duration.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
 #import <Protobuf/Duration.pbobjc.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         <protobuf/Duration.pbobjc.h>
/Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Protobuf/GPBWellKnownTypes.h:42:10: warning: non-portable path to file '<protobuf/Timestamp.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
 #import <Protobuf/Timestamp.pbobjc.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         <protobuf/Timestamp.pbobjc.h>
In file included from /Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/FirebaseMessaging/Firebase/Messaging/FIRMessagingRmq2PersistentStore.m:27:
In file included from /Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/FirebaseMessaging/Firebase/Messaging/Protos/GtalkCore.pbobjc.h:27:
/Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Protobuf/GPBProtocolBuffers.h:55:10: warning: non-portable path to file '<protobuf/Any.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
 #import <Protobuf/Any.pbobjc.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         <protobuf/Any.pbobjc.h>
/Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Protobuf/GPBProtocolBuffers.h:56:10: warning: non-portable path to file '<protobuf/Api.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
 #import <Protobuf/Api.pbobjc.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         <protobuf/Api.pbobjc.h>
/Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Protobuf/GPBProtocolBuffers.h:57:10: warning: non-portable path to file '<protobuf/Duration.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
 #import <Protobuf/Duration.pbobjc.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         <protobuf/Duration.pbobjc.h>
/Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Protobuf/GPBProtocolBuffers.h:58:10: warning: non-portable path to file '<protobuf/Empty.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
 #import <Protobuf/Empty.pbobjc.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         <protobuf/Empty.pbobjc.h>
/Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Protobuf/GPBProtocolBuffers.h:59:10: warning: non-portable path to file '<protobuf/FieldMask.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
 #import <Protobuf/FieldMask.pbobjc.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         <protobuf/FieldMask.pbobjc.h>
/Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Protobuf/GPBProtocolBuffers.h:60:10: warning: non-portable path to file '<protobuf/SourceContext.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
 #import <Protobuf/SourceContext.pbobjc.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         <protobuf/SourceContext.pbobjc.h>
/Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Protobuf/GPBProtocolBuffers.h:61:10: warning: non-portable path to file '<protobuf/Struct.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
 #import <Protobuf/Struct.pbobjc.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         <protobuf/Struct.pbobjc.h>
/Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Protobuf/GPBProtocolBuffers.h:62:10: warning: non-portable path to file '<protobuf/Timestamp.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
 #import <Protobuf/Timestamp.pbobjc.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         <protobuf/Timestamp.pbobjc.h>
/Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Protobuf/GPBProtocolBuffers.h:63:10: warning: non-portable path to file '<protobuf/Type.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
 #import <Protobuf/Type.pbobjc.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         <protobuf/Type.pbobjc.h>
/Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Protobuf/GPBProtocolBuffers.h:64:10: warning: non-portable path to file '<protobuf/Wrappers.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
 #import <Protobuf/Wrappers.pbobjc.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         <protobuf/Wrappers.pbobjc.h>
13 warnings generated.
=== BUILD TARGET FirebaseStorage OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
In file included from /Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/FirebaseMessaging/Firebase/Messaging/FIRMessagingRmqManager.m:25:
In file included from /Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/FirebaseMessaging/Firebase/Messaging/Protos/GtalkCore.pbobjc.h:27:
In file included from /Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Protobuf/GPBProtocolBuffers.h:44:
/Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Protobuf/GPBWellKnownTypes.h:40:10: warning: non-portable path to file '<protobuf/Any.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
 #import <Protobuf/Any.pbobjc.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         <protobuf/Any.pbobjc.h>
/Users/deepan/smart-school-nise-update_31_03_19/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Protobuf/GPBWellKnownTypes.h:41:10: warning: non-portable path to file '<protobuf/Duration.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
 #import <Protobuf/Duration.pbobjc.h>


3 warnings and 8 errors generated.
```